# Adding Children To Empty SpriteNode

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

I've created a simple project where I have a file called **GameScene.sks**. This contains a single empty node called `object1`. In another file called **Scene2.sks**, I have a single sprite node. How would I add this node to the empty node in GameScene.sks? I've followed the Session 608 video from WWDC, but nothing shows up on screen. This is just a "test" project because I want to be able to add many children from one .sks to an empty node via this method, similar to what Apple demonstrated with their totem example in WWDC Session 608. I must be missing something. Here's my code below:

**GameScene.m**

```
#import "GameScene.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    SKNode *object1 = [self childNodeWithName:@"object1"];
    for (SKNode *child in [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"Scene2"].children) {
        [object1 addChild: [child copy]];
    }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

**GameScene.sks**

[image: GameScene.sks]

**Scene2.sks**

[image: Scene2.sks]

Note: The AppDelegate.h file was modified so that `unarchiveFromFile` could be used in GameScene.m. Here's the code:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface SKScene (Unarchive)

+ (instancetype)unarchiveFromFile:(NSString *)file;

@end

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet SKView *skView;

@end
```

Comment: Are you getting an error ? I don't see your implementation for `unarchiveFile` method.

Comment: No, there's no error, it just doesn't show anything in the view. The implementation for `unarchiveFromFile` is in AppDelegate.m. It's already there by default in a SpriteKit project. I simply include AppDelegate.h and made the method public so that I could use it in another class. I'll post the code for AppDelegate.h. There was some modification to it.

Comment: Code works fine for me, as long as the unarchiveFromFile implementation is present. Problem could be any number of things on your side, in terms of presenting the scene or setup of your objects in the .sks etc. Do you know how to use debugger to confirm that code is hit ? Next step would be to maybe drop a breakpoint and check each node's position to ensure they are onscreen.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use the debugger. Actually, it just crashes now. It seems that `object1` the SKNode is nil. The code is trying to add a child to that node and it crashes. So is an empty node a node that is nil?

Comment: Check your GameScene.sks to ensure that object1 still exists.

Comment: Yes, it's there. It was created via the pane on the right side from the object library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68908/discussion-between-prototypical-and-02fentym).